# Limit distribution of Ornstein-Uhlenbeck equation

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let
\begin{equation*}
X_t=xe^{-\lambda t}+\sigma e^{-\lambda t}\int_0^t e^{\lambda s} dB_s
\end{equation*}

be the solution of Ornstein-Uhlenbeck equation where $B$ is Brownian motion, and $x,\sigma,\lambda$ are all constants. Compute 
\begin{equation*}
\liminf_{t\rightarrow \infty}\frac{X_t}{\sqrt{\log t}}\quad \text{ and  } \quad\limsup_{t\rightarrow \infty}\frac{X_t}{\sqrt{\log t}}
\end{equation*} 
Furthermore, What can be said of $\liminf_{t\rightarrow \infty}X_t$ and $\limsup_{t\rightarrow \infty}X_t$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\al}{\alpha}
\newcommand{\de}{\delta}
\newcommand{\De}{\Delta}
\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\ga}{\gamma}
\newcommand{\Ga}{\Gamma}
\newcommand{\la}{\lambda}
\newcommand{\si}{\sigma}
\newcommand{\Si}{\Sigma}
\newcommand{\thh}{\theta}
\newcommand{\om}{\omega}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal{F}}
\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{\mathsf E}} 
\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{\mathsf Var}} 
\renewcommand{\P}{\operatorname{\mathsf P}}
\newcommand{\ii}[1]{\operatorname{\mathsf I}\{#1\}} 
\newcommand{\tf}{\widetilde{f}}$

By vertical and horizontal rescaling, without loss of generality (wlog) $\la=\si=1$. It is then known (see e.g. [formula (1.5)](http://www.math.utk.edu/~xchen/limit-LIL.pdf)) that wlog 
\begin{equation}
 X_t=\frac{B_{e^t}}{e^{t/2}}. 
\end{equation}
So, 
\begin{equation}
 \limsup_{t\to\infty}\frac{X_t}{\sqrt{\ln t}}
 =\lim_{t\to\infty}\sup_{s\ge t}\frac{B_{e^s}}{e^{s/2}\sqrt{\ln s}}
 =\lim_{t\to\infty}\sup_{u\ge e^t}\frac{B_u}{\sqrt{u\ln\ln u}}=\sqrt2
\end{equation}
by the law of the iterated logarithm for the Brownian motion. 
Similarly, 
\begin{equation}
 \liminf_{t\to\infty}\frac{X_t}{\sqrt{\ln t}}
=-\sqrt2. 
\end{equation}
For arbitrary positive real $\la$ and $\si$ we then have 
\begin{equation}
 \limsup_{t\to\infty}\frac{X_t}{\sqrt{\ln t}}=\si\sqrt2,\quad
 \liminf_{t\to\infty}\frac{X_t}{\sqrt{\ln t}}=-\si\sqrt2; 
\end{equation}
the latter limits do not depend on $\la$.

It then also follows that 
\begin{equation}
 \limsup_{t\to\infty}X_t=\si\sqrt2\,\lim_{t\to\infty}\sqrt{\ln t}=\infty,\quad
 \liminf_{t\to\infty}X_t=-\infty. 
\end{equation}